# Kafka S3 source connector does not include key to the messages with SMT

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have set up kafka s3 source connector that reads messages that have been inserted to the bucket by s3 sink connector. I noticed that source connector does not include by default the key in the message even if it is stored in the bucket. So I found the way how to configure transformation to include message key from field in message value. This is my transformation setting inside the source connector:

```
    transforms: copyIdToKey,extractKeyFromStruct
    transforms.copyIdToKey.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
    transforms.copyIdToKey.fields: payloadKey
    transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
    transforms.extractKeyFromStruct.field: payloadKey
```

and this is my message:

```
{
    "header": {
        "eventKey": "441bf7d6-a4bb-4711-9d95-6aaff7e052f9",
        "sourceEventId": null,
        "createdTimestamp": "2023-07-05T23:36:00.372Z",
        "eventProducer": "test-producer",
        "payloadType": "Businessprocess"
    },
    "payload": {
        ...
    },
    "payloadClass": "",
    "payloadKey": "c6fc638b-ef2b-471b-a6cc-a211a49a6af1"
}
```

Basically I want to use value from **payloadKey** field as message key. However when I use this transformations no messages are produced by source connector to the topic. When I remove transformations config messages are produced but with **null** key.

What am I actually doing wrong when using the transformations?

checked documentation, blogs other stackoverflow questions